# Determine a DOM element's document?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am getting a reference to a DOM element from a WYSIWYG Editor.

I don't understand JS nor the WYSIWYG Editor (CKEditor) that deeply yet, but it somehow seems to be a pointer or other direct reference to the actual element that resides in an IFRAME within the WYSIWYG editor. At least, when I `console.log` the element, I get a link that, when clicked, opens the actual element in Firebug.

**Is there a way to get a reference to this element's `document` object within the IFRAME?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the DOM element reference, you can use the [`ownerDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.ownerDocument) property:

```
var ownerDoc = someElement.ownerDocument;
```

Comment: You're welcome @Pekka, it will work without problems on most browsers... http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that specific editor, but if it has a reasonably normal implementation of the DOM, each node (including the DOM element to which you get a reference) has a `parentNode` read-only property that references its parent node.  By following the chain of `parentNode` references, you're moving upwards in the DOM tree and should eventually reach the `document` you want.

(The `ownerDocument` property offers a more immediate solution, but it was not supported in some old browsers such as IE 5.5 -- if you don't have to worry about such "archaeology" issues, it's fine, but `parentNode` works even more broadly).

Comment: Cheers Alex, and very good additional information. I can assume IE > 6 so ownerDocument will do for me. I would upvote this but have run out of votes for today.

Comment: @Pekka, NP, I'm maxed out for the day in any case;-).  Yeah, mostly one doesn't have to worry about IE <6 any more (worrying about IE6 is bad enough in the general case;-), but not knowing that editor I thought its DOM might be based on an underlying ancient browser, so I offered the "rock-solid" solution just in case;-)